# Can't run rar.exe through Process

Tags: java, command-line

I'm trying to unpack a rar file from my Java application.

I've found plenty of solutions on how to execute a command which works for stuff like `dir` etc on Windows. But it doesn't seem to work for any other application like `gcc` or `rar`. I know they both work because when I execute them in `cmd` they give me proper output.

However, I'd like to print the output they spit out in the `cmd`. I just don't really get why it works for `dir` and for nothing else (none "native" commands).

The `exitVal` always seems to be 0..

```
    try {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

        Process pr = rt.exec("cmd /c rar.exe"); //Does not work

        //Process pr = rt.exec("cmd /c dir") // This works
        //Process pr = rt.exec("gcc.exe");

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

        String line=null;

        while((line=input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        int exitVal = pr.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Exited with error code "+exitVal);
    }catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("An error occured. Are you sure the executable is in your Windows PATH?");
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.me);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: capture errorstream by replacing pr.getInputStream() with pr.getErrorStream() and it will tell you if there is anything wrong with executing the command.

Comment: I like the answer from A Paul. Now you also have to think about performance. If your code will run on a WebServer or at least with a lot of calls, it's much better to use some java library, calling external programs with `Runtime.exec()` can kill an ApplicationServer if it's part of a commonly used feature...

Answer (score 1):

Can you try something like below

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"c:\\some_path\\UnRAR.exe", "e","c:\\some_another_path\\Archive.rar"});
```

or you can use below library

```
https://github.com/edmund-wagner/junrar
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant straight away run rar.exe on cmd. It will give
'rar.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

You either specify the path or add the path of Rar in environment variable

Comment: I did what Sanjeev pointed out in the comments and I get the "not recognized as an internal command". This is strange because the rar.exe is added to my PATH. So it would appear that the PATH is not fully loaded when using the Process class to execute rar.exe ?